# JPA mapping: Reusing entities in multiple relationships

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, entity

Let's say I have:

```
class Unit {
    private TextContainer source;
    private List<TextContainer> targets;
}
```

Can I annotate class TextContainer in such a way that it works within both relationships?
TextContainer must be either source or target.

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate the relations with `TextContainer` in the `Unit` class. Something like this:

```
class Unit {

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private TextContainer source;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private List<TextContainer> targets;
}
```